# Missing Letter Function - Why is it returning undefined?

Tags: javascript

I'm doing one of the bonfires on Free Code Camp and I'm close to the end, but there's one last bit I can't figure out!

The function should take a string and return what letter is missing (based on the alphabet a-z). It works fine except when the letter that's missing is 'i', where it returns undefined.

I put an additional if statement in to check that when the missing letter is 'i', it meets the criteria of the other if statement (and therefore should execute those lines of code) and it matched, so I've no idea why it would return undefined.

```js
function fearNotLetter(str) {
  missingLetter = '';
  charCode = 0;
    
  for (i = 0; i < str.length -1 ; i++) {
    charCode = str.charCodeAt(i);

    if (str.charCodeAt(i + 1)-charCode == 2) {            
      missingLetter = str.charCodeAt(i)+1;
      missingLetter = String.fromCharCode(missingLetter);
    } else { 
      missingLetter = undefined;
    }
  }
    
  console.log(missingLetter);
  return missingLetter;
}
    
fearNotLetter("abcdefghjklmno");
```

Really appreciate any help anyone can give.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys - that's great! For my learning, any thoughts on why it was only certain strings that returned undefined and not others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are setting the value in every round without a missing letter to `undefined` - even if you found one in the loop before.

I suggest to declare all variable before use with `var` keyword and initialize `missingLetter` with `undefined`.

Then you can `break` the loop if the missing letter is found.

```js
function fearNotLetter(str) {
    var missingLetter = undefined,
        charCode,
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < str.length - 1 ; i++) {
        charCode = str.charCodeAt(i);
        if (str.charCodeAt(i + 1) - charCode == 2) {
            missingLetter = String.fromCharCode(charCode + 1);
            break;
        }
    }
    return missingLetter;
}

console.log(fearNotLetter("abcdefghjklmno"));
```

Comment: thanks, that's brilliant! I never though to break the code once it's done!

Comment: There's not much point in initializing a variable to undefined. Also, it would be simpler to just return the value when it's found instead of breaking the loop – you wouldn't even need a variable then.

Comment: @Juhana, right that is posible to exit the loop and function with return, but op had a variable and it was just to show how to deal with a default value.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, you are missing to **break** the loop once you get the missing letter and in the **next iteration missing letter is set to undefined**.

```js
function fearNotLetter(str) {
  missingLetter = '';
  charCode = 0;


  for (i = 0; i < str.length -1 ; i++) 
  {

    charCode = str.charCodeAt(i);
    
    if (str.charCodeAt(i + 1)-charCode == 2) {
    
      missingLetter = str.charCodeAt(i)+1;
      missingLetter = String.fromCharCode(missingLetter);
      break;
    }  
    else 
    { 
      missingLetter = undefined;
    }
  }
  console.log(missingLetter);
  return missingLetter;
}
fearNotLetter("abcdefghjklmno");
```